# Accessing Scala Case Class parameters in method

Tags: scala

I am working on a code where I need to access the fields of a case class based on field name in a method. Explaining in the below code

```
Case Class Department(
            projectId: String,
            name: Option[String],
            id1: Option[String],
            id2: Option[String],
            id3: Option[String],
            age: Option[Int]
){

def logicOnId(): Boolean = {
  ???
  }
}
```

I want to write the same logic on all the three ids. I can write it as follows:

```
def logicOnId1(): Boolean = {
  someLogic(this.id1)
  }

def logicOnId2(): Boolean = {
  someLogic(this.id2)
  }

def logicOnId3(): Boolean = {
  someLogic(this.id3)
  }
```

But this is not an ideal way since it is the same logic on different columns. So, I want the process/way to write a method so that it can be used on multiple fields like

```
def logicOnId(input: String): Boolean = {
  someLogic(input)
  }
```

where this input is `id1` or `id2` or `id3` as a String.

Comment: You can use reflection (runtime would be fine in your case), but it's not something encouraged.

Comment: Can you please provide the steps or any article for achieving this using reflection ??

Comment: Sure, here's the [scaladoc about runtime reflection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/environment-universes-mirrors.html)!

Comment: 1. Runtime reflection is not recommended. 2. Having business logic on case class is not recommended.

Comment: @cchantep Completely right!

Comment: Maybe storing the 3 IDs in a `Map` would better fit your need?

Comment: Also note the library [nameOf](https://github.com/dwickern/scala-nameof) could partially simplify your code.

Answer (score 1):

No need to go down the route of runtime reflection, just use good type modeling:

```scala
final case class Department(
    projectId: String,
    name: Option[String],
    id1: Option[String],
    id2: Option[String],
    id3: Option[String],
    age: Option[Int]
) {
  private def someLogic(input: Option[String]): Boolean =
    ???

  def logicOnId(id: ID): Boolean =
    id match {
      case ID.ID1 =>
        someLogic(this.id1)

      case ID.ID2 =>
        someLogic(this.id2)

      case ID.ID2 =>
        someLogic(this.id3)
    }
}

sealed trait ID
object ID {
  final case object ID1 extends ID
  final case object ID2 extends ID
  final case object ID3 extends ID
}
```

Comment: I would use [nameOf](https://github.com/dwickern/scala-nameof) library to avoid the `sealed trait` in this case. Not sure it works inside the case class itself though.